# JSON Data loading Issue local storing

Tags: javascript, html, json, storage

I'm trying to make an incremental game for learning purposes, and I'm facing a problem when saving users data locally.

For example, when I click on a button, it saves the value from the var "Food" :

```
localStorage.setItem("food",JSON.stringify(food));
```

And another button to load the save, linked to this function :

```
function loadFood() {

document.getElementById("food").innerHTML = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("food"));

}
```

However, my value Food is changing only when I press on the button. The value changes for like 1 second and then it goes back to 0.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: it looks like you have your 'loadfood' LHS and RHS of the `=` around the wrong way.. im assuming you want to assign the getItem('food') value into the element.. so just switch the order and you should be set

Comment: Why are you going to store JSON at first place?

Comment: Is `localStorage.getItem('food')` set somewhere else? Also, if you want to observe the value of `food`, you should use `console.log(localStorage.getItem('food'))` and see it in developer console (right click, Inspect Element).

Comment: The fact that the value changes back to zero suggests to me that you are executing code where you aren't expecting it (for example initializing food to 0 even after having set it to something else.  Without more code, this is difficult to diagnose.

Comment: Thank you all for answering. I've kinda solved the problem : It shows me now the right value, and it stays. But when I press on another button used to add 1 food each time I click, its starting from 0 again, its not taking care of the number saved :/

Answer (score 0):

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("food")) = document.getElementById("food").innerHTML;
```

Should be this -

```
 document.getElementById("food").innerHTML = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("food"));
```

Comment: Just checked my code, I wrote it this way , idk why I switched when I asked here :o anyway, the problem is still present :/

Comment: Try to print JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("food")) like this -- console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("food"))); and see if it actually has a value in it? and are you sure localstorage is supported in your browser?

Comment: It shows me a value in the console and at the same time Undefined in my web page , and I'm on the last version of Chrome it shouldnt be a problem :o